# Firefox automatically closing an HTML element too early - IE and Chrome OK

Tags: php, html, firefox

Can anyone tell me why Firefox would close a form early by adding a `</form>`? It closes the form well before the submit button - so the form then won't submit.

The whole code for the form is a bit long to post here. It works fine in Chrome and IE, but Firefox seems to close the form early and removes the later `</form>`.

The html is being output from PHP. Not sure if this would make a difference?

Editing in firebug doesn't work either. Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It might do so because of invalid markup ... another tag which isn't closed, or ones that are closed in the wrong sequence.  You can always post the markup somewhere like jsfiddle.net .

Comment: Strip out the unessential stuff - we need *some* code.

Comment: I had an issue where Firefox removed <form> tag when I did not have a closing one.  I may be wrong here and maybe something else removed the form tag, but .... that was my experience here.  HTML passed to the browser definitely had the tag (but not the closing one)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a browser closes a form or div unexpectedly, it's usually because there's some kind of mistake in the code - like a closing div instead of an opening one.

I suggest you feed your code to the [w3c Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), and fix the errors.

Comment: It's been a long day. I seem to have forgotten the basics!

Comment: This just happened to me, in my case I forgot to close an `<image>` tag. Thanks for the help. +1

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone tell me why Firefox would close a form early by adding a ? It closes the form well before the submit button - so the form then won't submit.

This usually happens because you have a construct that should be interpreted as a form end tag or is seriously invalid enough that the browser is recovering from the error badly.

> The whole code for the form is a bit long to post here.

No, it isn't (although if you can create a reduced test case that still demonstrates the problem then that would be preferred.

> The html is being output from PHP. Not sure if this would make a difference?

It wouldn't. Browsers only care about what is in the HTTP response, not how it got there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a validator to make sure your code is correct?

You can get [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to do the validation for you, or send your code to http://validator.w3.org/

That will tell you pretty quickly if you have some questionable markup that's causing the Firefox behavior.